# Does makeappx.exe exist in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to pack my program in azure release pipeline using the makeappx.exe. 
But I get the following error:

`'makeappx' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I use `windows-2019` hosted agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does makeappx.exe exist in azure pipeline?

Indeed, I also could reproduce this issue on my side. That because **`makeappx.exe` is a external command, can not be recognized by Windows in an arbitrary directory**.

In order to investigate this issue, I add a copy task to copy the default SDK folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

[image]

Obviously, the `makeappx.exe` does not exist under the default folder.

According to the [Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md), we could to know the windows-2019 hosted agent including Windows10 SDK `16299`, `17134`, `17763`, `18362`.

So, to invoke `makeappx.exe`, we could use the full path of this file, like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\makeappx.exe
```

As test, it works fine on the Windows-2019 hosted agent.

Hope this helps.